# Best Practice: null handling

Tags: java

Is this a good practice?

1. `boolean isNotNull = somevalue != null;`

*Instead of checking somevalue != null multiple times*

2. `new SomeClass(null)`

where SomeClass has a parameter of ENUM

*there are certain scenarios that ENUM can be null*

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to avoid null values if you can. Scenario you're describing seems like one where that's a feasible choice.

For example, you could define neutral ("null") behavior with additional ENUM value.

There are also other attractive options for limiting NullPointerExceptions:

- Java 8 tries to solve NPE issues with introducing **[Optionals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)**
- You can also follow a design pattern **[Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)**
- There is also an option to mark values as **[@Nullable and @NotNull](https://medium.com/@jintin/nullable-nonnull-dba2fde14192)**

I would also recommend reading a bit about how Kotlin deals with null values, it would extend your understanding of them.

Comment: I think the question is actually asking whether it is better to do the equality check once and store the result, or do the same equality check in multiple places in the code.

Comment: Not sure I can follow the question in that matter. Do you see a way you could edit the question to better describe the concern?

Comment: @VGR yes that is the question.